# Can we set the element ID for component created in the code like the ID in application model (e4xmi)?

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, osgi-bundle, e4

I created a RCP app with a part. In the part, I created a TreeViewer. Can I set an ID for this viewer so that others plugins can find this viewer by ID? How can we acquire this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't do this.

The contents of a part are not in the application model and can't have model ids.

You have to use the `findPart` method of `EPartService` to find the part and then call some method that you write in the part object to get the viewer.

```java
MPart part = partService.findPart("part id");

MyPartClass myclass = (MyPartClass)part.getObject();

TreeViewer viewer = myclass.getViewer();
```